# Transfer file from one machine to another using AS2 transfer protocol

Tags: java

I have transfer file to the client and receive file from our client using AS2. I got some help but that not completely help to solve my issue. Someone suggested to use openAS2 to send/receive the file. I used openAS2 but I have some issue which I didn't understand - Where I install our key and clients key in openAS2? I have one folder in which some file is there and I have to send those files one by one to the clients?Where I have set the folder name to poll?How I test the configuration of openAS2 whether its working fine or not?

Thanks in Advance for your help and co-operation.

Comment: https://developer.adroitlogic.com/as2gateway/docs/as2-gateway/overview/as2-protocol-operation.html

Answer (score 0):

You should install your key in the key store file of the openas2 installation. By default it ships with a key store which locates in config/as2_certs.p12. You can import your key to that key store. For configuring file polling paths, change the AS2DirectoryPollingModule elements in the config/config.xml file.

Refer this for more information - https://medium.com/@manjulapiyumal/getting-start-with-as2-protocol-using-as2gateway-and-openas2-796249cfd3ac